# On page refresh, maintain the navbar state

Tags: javascript, css, angular, typescript

I have a sidebar menu that contains a multiple level menu. In case I selected a child submenu I want that the selector navbar remain activated in child submenu after refreshing the page. Is that possibile?

Here some of code:

```
<ng-template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="navItems">
     <ng-template [ngIf]="item.divider">
       <li class="nav-divider"></li>
      </ng-template>
      <ng-template [ngIf]="item.title">
       <li class="nav-title">{{item.name | translate}}</li>
      </ng-template>

<ng-template [ngIf]="item.children && item.childrenVisible && !item.title 
    && (!item.children[0].children || item.children[0].children.length == 
 0)">
      <li [hidden]="itemHidden(item.keyPage) || !item.visible" class="nav- 
           item nav-dropdown" appNavDropdown>
         <a class="nav-link nav-dropdown-toggle" href="#" 
         appNavDropdownToggle>
            <i class="nav-icon {{item.icon}}"></i> {{ item.name | 
                translate }}
          <span *ngIf="item.badge" [ngClass]="'badge badge-' + 
              item.badge.variant">{{ item.badge.text }}</span>
         </a>
         <ul class="nav-dropdown-items">
            <ng-template ngFor let-subitem [ngForOf]="item.children">
               <li [hidden]="itemHidden(subitem.keyPage) || 
                  !subitem.visible" class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" routerLinkActive="active" [routerLink]=" 
                 [subitem.url]">
                <i class="nav-icon {{subitem.icon}}"></i> {{ subitem.name 
                    | translate }}
                <span *ngIf="subitem.badge" [ngClass]="'badge badge-' + 
                   subitem.badge.variant">{{ subitem.badge.text }}</span>
              </a>
            </li>
          </ng-template>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ng-template>
</ng-template>



   public itemHidden(keyPage): boolean {
        return false;
   }
```

Comment: you  can  import  the `router` in your component.ts  to get the `current  url` and then use the `ngclass="{  'active': checkUrl(url) }"` where `checkUrl` fuunction compare it with current route

Comment: mmh.. and how can activate the selected child and after refresh open and activate the submenu? in my case I can't activate any child

Answer (score 0):

You can save the state of your navigation on click of your child menu and on ngOnInt you can check if the state exists then active the child.

Answer (score 0):

Store the state in the URL as a fragment

```
https://myapp.com/mypage#tab_state
```

by using the command,

```
window.location.hash='#tab_state'
```

By reading the value on page refresh, you set the appropriate child as active.

Comment: the is that the submenu should be open and active on child also when refresh the page.. but it isnt open

Comment: yes, the logic needs to be covered within your code.

Answer (score 0):

You can use RouterLinkActive , this directive lets you add a CSS class to an element when the link's route becomes active

https://angular.io/api/router/RouterLinkActive

Comment: Could you include a code example in the answer on how to use the mentioned library? One-liner answers are against policy.